# Looping an object in react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, jsx

I have an object inside modalProps.rows that looks like the following:

[image]

I need to build a select menu with it. This is what I have done so fare

```
  <Select name="replace_id" onChange={handleActivityAreaChange}>
  {console.log(modalProps.rows)}
    {Object.keys(modalProps.rows).map(({ id, name }, index) =>
      <option key={index}
        value={id}>
        {name}
      </option>
    )}
  </Select>
```

The above gives me no error but the dropdown list remains empty. What am I missing?

---

Afer playing arround a little this is what I did

```
  const options = []

  Object.keys(modalProps.rows).forEach(key => {
    options.push({value: modalProps.rows[key].id, label: modalProps.rows[key].name});
  });

  const renderActivityAreaList = () => (
    <Flex width="100%">
      {t('entities.activityAreas.used')}
      <Select name="replace_id" options={options} onChange={handleActivityAreaChange} />
    </Flex>
  )
```

The above worked as expected ... but I still wish I could understand what was wrong with my previous attempt.

Comment: You should more information, how your fetching the data and using it.

Comment: given your update, it's likely related to Select Component and what expects to receive. I updated my answer, and it should be working just like yours fwiw .

Answer (score 0):

you should use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) instead to retrieve your object data:

```
  <Select name="replace_id" onChange={handleActivityAreaChange}>
  {console.log(modalProps.rows)}
    {Object.values(modalProps.rows).map(({ id, name }) =>
      <option key={id}
        value={id}>
        {name}
      </option>
    )}
  </Select>
```

**note:** prefer to pass your id as key than array's index

**update**

given your implementation it may be related to Select component what expects to receive. if you do like:

```
const options = Object.values(modalProps.rows).map(({ id, name }) => ({ value: id, label: name }))

const renderActivityAreaList = () => (
  <Flex width="100%">
    {t('entities.activityAreas.used')}
    <Select name="replace_id" options={options} onChange={handleActivityAreaChange} />
  </Flex>
)
```

you are likely to face the same outcome

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just tryed the above and got the same result ... no errors but menu empty.

Comment: then you need to show, what you done in your code, we can't predict what went wrong.

Comment: The data in modalProps.rows seems to be in a sub object. I am pretty sure the problem is in the way i map it but I am not sure how to do it. If i log Object.values(modalProps.rows).map((option)  option is empty but it create an empty log line for the right amount of data. If I log odalProps.rows I see the above values in the picture I provided.

Comment: for the given object structure Object.values should work. you can try console log one element like modalProps.rows[30], and render instead only <option key={modalProps.rows[30].id} value={modalProps.rows[30].id}>{modalProps.rows[30].name}</option> to check if it displays correctly